# Show an alert or a message when a page is not opened with IE browser

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have created a SharePoint 2013 page with HTML Iframe. As Iframe is not working with certain browsers, for example, Chrome. I need to alert or show a message when the page is not opened with IE. Can you please let me know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that detecting browsers is not reliable, but you can try this:

```
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode; 
if (!isIE) {
    alert("This is not IE");
}
```

This is not my work, I got it from [How to detect Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser)

This trick uses duck-typing. Please go to this page and read the pros and cons before using it in production.

EDIT:
I believe my first answer met your question, but since you elaborated further in your comment, I have another code snippet for you.

As previously stated: browser detection is not reliable but since you want to try it, here's a suggestion. This combines the duck-typing example with checking the user agent:

```
if ((window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Edge') == -1) && !(/*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode)) {
    alert('This is not IE or Edge');
} 
else {
    alert('This is IE or Edge');
}
```

I have tested this in IE11, Edge, Chrome and Firefox Dev ed. You can try window.navigator.userAgent in any browser to see the difference.

Also, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31721250/how-to-target-windows-10-edge-browser-with-javascript) post.

Comment: Hi Papageno, can you please advise how to detect if the browser is not IE OR Edge, then send the alert? Is it possible to detect two browsers? thanks,

Comment: Please find my advise in my updated answer,

Answer (score 0):

You can check if current browser is Chrome and alert a warning message like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   IEBrowserDetection();

 function IEBrowserDetection() {
   if (navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome")>= 0) {
        // insert conditional Chrome code here
        alert("Current browser is Chrome, this page needs to be accessed by IE, please use IE instead");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```